# How to generate a formatted unique ascending identifier database-independently

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to generate an internal identifier (not an @Id) for one of my domain entities with a fix format:

```
2012-FLD-00000001

2012-FLD-00000002

...

2012-FLD-99999999

2013-FLD-00000001

2013-FLD-00000002

...

2013-FLD-99999999
```

I have no idea how to implement this feature database-independently by using JPA (and Hibernate as the provider).

What I need is:

```
 - Uniqueness
 - Increasing numbers
 - Restarting the sequence in new years
 - A clear and hack-free solution
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with handling this--especially the uniqueness requirement--in the persistence layer is that you can't guarantee that your app is the only app hitting the database. In fact, I'll bet that right now there are at least two more apps that will walk right past Java--your dbms's graphical interface, and your dbms's command-line interface.  (The last full-time contract I did had applications written in more than two dozen languages over the course of 30 years hitting the main production database.)

Brute force always works. (But might create a hot spot.)

You can generate your internal identifiers today, and store them in a table.

```
create table internal_iden (
  iden char(17) primary key 
    check (iden ~ '2[0-9]{3}-FLD-[0-9]{8}'),
  taken_by varchar(15) null,
  taken_at timestamp null
);
```

The CHECK() constraint guarantees that inserted values match the regular expression.  (PostgreSQL supports POSIX regular expressions among others; the "~" operator tells the dbms this comparison expects a POSIX regular rexpression.) Depending on your application requirements, you may or may not want other tables to set a foreign key reference to this internal_iden table.

```
insert into internal_iden (iden) values
('2012-FLD-00000001'),
('2012-FLD-00000002'),
('2012-FLD-00000003'),
('2012-FLD-00000004'),
('2012-FLD-00000005'),
('2012-FLD-00000006'),
('2012-FLD-00000007'),
('2012-FLD-00000008'),
('2012-FLD-00000000'),
('2012-FLD-00000010'),
('2012-FLD-00000011'),
('2012-FLD-00000012');
```

Then you can create a stored procedure or a function to wrap these two statements in a single transaction.

```
select min(iden)
from internal_iden
where taken_by is null;

update internal_iden
set taken_by = 'server1',
    taken_at = current_timestamp
where iden = (select min(iden)
              from internal_iden
              where taken_by is null);
```

Actually, in the stored procedure, you can replace that subquery in the last WHERE clause with the literal value of the iden you got from the SELECT statement. A partial index on taken_by might help performance. (If your dbms supports partial indexes.)

```
create index ix1 on internal_iden (taken_by)
where (taken_by is null);
```

The maximum number of rows per year is about 100 million. There are several ways to handle that many rows.

- Create them all at once, and live with it.
- Create them all at once, and partition the table.
- Create a million, and run a cron job that counts the free idens and adds another million when the count gets low.
- Let the stored procedure take care of adding idens as needed.

Keep partitioning in mind if you go forward with this idea.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `Hibernate.Id.TableGenerator` which uses a table to persist information to generate an id

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JPA you can create an event listener for the pre-persist event.
The event listener (I called it DomainIDGenerator) will then inject the next domain ID into your entity.

**Listener class**

```
public class DomainIDGenerator {
    private static final AtomicInteger counter;
    private static int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

    static {
        //TODO initialize 'counter' with the last value used in the DB
    }

    private static int getYear() {
        int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (currentYear != year) {
            year = currentYear;
            counter.set(0);
        }
        return currentYear;
    }

    private static synchronized String getNextID() {
        return String.format("%d-FDL-%08d", getYear(), counter.incrementAndGet());
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void injectDomainID(Object entity) {
        if (entity instanceof MyEntity) {
            ((MyEntity) entity).setDomainID(getNextID());
        }
    }
}
```

META-INF/persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
        <persistence-unit name="...">
            <mapping-file>META-INF/persistence-defaults.xml</mapping-file>
            ...
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

META-INF/persistence-defaults.xml:

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
        <persistence-unit-metadata>
            <persistence-unit-defaults>
                <entity-listeners>
                    <entity-listener class="org.example.DomainIDGenerator" />
                </entity-listeners>
            </persistence-unit-defaults>
        </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```